# JavaScript: Call base function from prototyped inheritance

Tags: javascript, function, call, prototype, radix

```
var super_class = function(p) {
    this.p = p + 1;
    this.method = function(a, b) {
        // some code
    };
};

var base_class = function(o) {
    this.o = o;
    super_class.call(this, o);
    this.method = function(a, b) {
        // call super_class .method();
        // some code
    }
}

base_class.prototype = new super_class();

var bc = new base_class(0);
var v1 = bc.o; // 0
var v2 = bc.p; // 1
```

How can I call the super_class `method` when the name and properties are **supposed** to be identical. If I changed the name, I would just call `this.method(3, 4);` from within another function. I'm creating an extension class to another extension class, so changing the name of the function will not help me.

Also, storing the function in a private variable `var pmethod = this.method;` is sloppy at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current implementation has an error at `super_class(this, o);`. Either replace it with `super_class.call(this, o)`, or correctly implement an initializer method:

```
// Basic super class method.
var Super_class = function(p) {
    this.init(p); // Call initializer
};

// Define prototype properties and methods
Super_class.prototype = {
    constructor: Super_class,
    init: function(p) { this.p = p + 1; },
    method: function(a, b) {
        console.log("Super class method, arguments: " + [a,b]);
    }
};

// Define base_class
var Base_class = function(o) {
    this.o = o;   // Initialize `o` property
    this.init(o); // Initialize p variable through the initializer
};
// Extend `Base_class` prototype with `method`.
Base_class.prototype.method = function(a, b) {
    // Call the method from the parent = Super_class.prototype.method
    this.constructor.prototype.method(a, b);
};

Base_class.prototype = new Super_class; // Set prototype to `super_class`.

var bc = new Base_class(0);
var v1 = bc.o; // 0
var v2 = bc.p; // 1
bc.method('Hi: ', [v1, v2]); // Prints "Super class method, arguments: Hi [0,1]"
```

Alternatively, you can also push all methods of `Base_class` in `Base_class` itself and/or create a reference to the parent class:

```
// Define base_class
var Base_class = function(o) {
    var __super__ = this.constructor.prototype;
    this.o = o;   // Initialize `o` property
    this.init(o); // Initialize p variable through the initializer
    Base_class.prototype.method = function(a, b) {
        // Call the method from the parent = Super_class.prototype.method
        __super__.method(a, b);
    };
};
```

Comment: `this.constructor.call(this, o);` would cause multi-inheritance (more than one inheritance) to fail. `this.constructor(o);` is enough. `base_class.prototype = new super_class();` has already made sure all the properties of the super class being copied over to the new class.

Comment: Not to be rude, but in what way does this let me call `super_class.method();` from within `base_class.method();`

Comment: @BrianGraham Edited answer to answer *that* question. Your question's code was actually printing `0 and NaN` instead of `0 and 1`. Hence my previous answer.

Comment: I did have an error, and have just fixed it. Is there anyway to call super_class.method(); without declaring prototype methods outside the class function?

Comment: @BrianGraham Yes, you can use `this.blabla` to define `blabla`. I have shown two methods to accomplish this: Defining methods on the prototype, and defining methods on-the-fly. In either case, `this.constructor.prototype` points to `super_class`.

Comment: @RobW how could I have a third class inherit from the second class. My current attempt is recursively calling the parent-most class.

Comment: @BrianGraham Have you already defined an initializer for `Base_class`? If you want to have to chain an indefenite number of "classes", you'd better stick to the structure of `Super_class`: Using an initializer to initialize properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
var super_class = function(p) {
    this.p = p + 1;
    this.method = function(a, b) {
        // some code
    };
};

var base_class = function(o) {
    this.o = o;
    super_class(o); // remove "this"
    this.method = function(a, b) {
         // call base.method();
         // some code
    }
}

base_class.prototype = new super_class();

base_class.prototype.constructor = base_class;  //important: pointing the constructor back to the base class.
```

This is what the basic inheritance is done in JavaScript. If you want to get something fancy , use

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
```

See http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html for more information.